# Receiving [FirebaseRemoteConfigOperation] Config not fetched, error: Internal Error. Status code: 503 on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Last week I migrated my Firebase library from cocoapods to SPM. It seemed woking fine and today I noticed my remote configs from firebase isn't working. Thus I am seeing below errors on my logs.

```
[FirebaseRemoteConfig][I-RCN000026] RCN Fetch failure. Response http error code: 503
[FirebaseRemoteConfigOperation] Config not fetched, error: Internal Error. Status code: 503
```

Is it something to do with SPM or on the code? Sometimes it works also

Firebase -v9.3.0
Project iOS v -13

Comment: Firebase remote config API's seems to be down at this moment, I am not sure if some specific versions are affected or it is a full outage.
There is no confirmation yet from Firebase that it is down too. We are experiencing this in our Flutter app in iOS too.